# Under android, why TThread.synchronize followed by CallInUIThread result in app crash?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I have the very simple code below that run under Android :

```
type

  TmyObject = class(Tobject)
  public
    fint: integer;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

destructor TmyObject.Destroy;
begin

  TThread.synchronize(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      fint := 26;
    end);

  CallInUIThread(
    procedure
    begin
    end);

  inherited;

end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var aObject: TmyObject;
begin
  aObject := TmyObject.Create;
  aObject.free;
end;
```

And i can't understand why it's crash with **class segmentation fault** when we click on Button1Click ?

What i know :

- IF i remove just the `TThread.synchronize` it's not crash
- IF i remove just the `CallInUIThread` it's not crash
- If remove the `fint := 26;` it's not crash
- IF i call `TThread.synchronize` + `CallInUIThread` outside of a destructor it's not crash

It's crash in the procedure below (when CallInUIThread finish)

```
function _InstClear(var Dest: TObject): Pointer;
{$IFDEF PUREPASCAL}
var
  P: Pointer;
begin
  Result := @Dest;
  if Dest <> nil then
  begin
    P := Pointer(Dest);
    Pointer(Dest) := nil;
    TObject(P).__ObjRelease;
  end;
end;
```

exactly inside

```
destructor TJavaLocal.Destroy;
begin
  TJNIResolver.DeleteGlobalRef(FObjectID);

  inherited;
end; <== here
```

below the Stack Trace :

```
System._InstClear(@0xa042672c: nil)
System._FinalizeArray(0xa042672c,0xa33c1af8,1)
System._FinalizeRecord(0xa0426720,0xa33c1c80)
System.TObject.CleanupInstance(0xa0426720)
System.TObject.FreeInstance(0xa0426720)
System._ClassDestroy(0xa0426720)
System.TObject.~TObject(0xa0426720,true)
System.TObject.__ObjRelease(0xa0426720)
System.TInterfacedObject._Release(0xa0426720)
:A231CC0E __stub_in16s__ZN6System17TInterfacedObject8_ReleaseEv24
System._IntfClear(@0xa0676cbc: nil)
System._FinalizeArray(0xa0676cbc,0xa313e480,1)
System._FinalizeRecord(0xa0676c98,0xa313e55c)
System.TObject.CleanupInstance(0xa0676c98)
System.TObject.FreeInstance(0xa0676c98)
System._ClassDestroy(0xa0676c98)
Androidapi.Jnibridge.TJavaLocal.~TJavaLocal(0xa0676c98,true)
System.TObject.__ObjRelease(0xa0676c98)
System._InstClear(@0xbe9c1b50: nil)
Androidapi.Jnibridge.dispatchToNative(0xb4857c00,0xbe9c1b9c,0xbe9c1ba0,0xbe9c1ba4,2691132568)
:A3A033EC ??
:A3A033EC ??
```

So it's let me suppose that it's an ARC problem, but i can't understand what i did wrong ? I m under delphi Berlin

**NOTE**

I start to be sure at 99% that it's a ARC bug

doing like this no crash :

```
type

  TmyObject = class(Tobject)
  public
    fint: integer;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure AnProcedure;
  end;

procedure TmyObject.AnProcedure;
begin

end;

destructor TmyObject.Destroy;
begin

  TThread.synchronize(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      fint := 26;
    end);

  CallInUIThread(AnProcedure);

  inherited;

end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var aObject: TmyObject;
begin
  aObject := TmyObject.Create;
  aObject.free;
end;
```

so maybe on of the procedure try to catch a strong reference to the self Object and then destroy it at the end, but at the end the object is already destroyed because it's was in the process of destroying.

Comment: I expect it's a bug in Delphi 10.1 Berlin. Given the call stack, I expect it is attempting to free the Runnable instance when it shouldn't, e.g. after it has already been free'd. Why that should happen only after using TThread.Synchronize etc has me beat. For what it's worth, the same code works in Tokyo, but as you know, CallInUIThread doesn't create a Runnable instance when being called in the main thread.

Comment: In addition, creating and destroying an instance of TmyObject in a separate thread (thus resulting in a Runnable instance being created) also succeeds without a crash in Tokyo

Comment: There is no multithreading code in your question. In the main thread you just created an object and through thread synchronization methods you're trying to execute some code. But there is still just one, main thread.

Comment: `TThread.Synchronize` should not be called from the main thread: *`Warning: Do not call Synchronize from within the main thread. This can cause an infinite loop.`*

Comment: @Victoria yes i made the more easy sample as possible. but multithread or not, it's not the problem, problem is why it's crash ;)

Comment: @LURD of course you can call synchronize from the main thread! from the mainThread synchronize just do `if CurrentThread.ThreadID = MainThreadID then FProcedure();` so i don't know what they say in the doc, but it's wrong

Comment: @DaveNottage: yes as you say this problem is probably connected to TRunnable, but it's completely crazy that it is only this exact combination (ie: thread.synchronize that do nothing else that just `if CurrentThread.ThreadID = MainThreadID then FProcedure();` followed by callinUiThread all of this inside a destructor of an object. at the end this will **probably** show how dangerous is ARC because i m suspicious this bug is connected to ARC.

Comment: I don't exactly have complete picture, but one thing is for sure you shouldn't call `CallInUIThread` that operates on object that is about to be destroyed - I would expect that to crash or if it does not then it is just mere luck and not working code - you should call `CallInUIThreadAndWaitFinishing`. The reason why it crashes in first case and not in second one - I can only speculate at the moment, but I guess it would also crash in the second one if you would do anything substantial with that object - since by the time that code is called your object would already be long dead.

Comment: @J... i m using berlin, you must know that tokyo not work right now for android :(

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar yes but as you see CallInUIThread don't do anything, the procedure is empty, so it's must catch nothing. you can not use CallInUIThreadAndWaitFinishing because when the app is finishing (destroying) then CallInUIThreadAndWaitFinishing will never return (you go infinite wait). also i confirm you it's not crash in the second case even if you do something substantial ! and remenber, for 1rt case, just remove the tthread.synchronize and also it's not crash !

Comment: Like I said I don't know exactly what is the problem and why that exact combination triggers error and I cannot debug myself to really see what is going on, but while that anonymous method itself does nothing it involves a lot more code to be executed since it is backed up by hidden interface and is not just plain static method call.

Comment: Ok, I see why CallInUIThreadAndWaitFinishing is not an option, I would move that cleanup code in BeforeDestruction, you have better chances that it will work properly from there.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar in beforedestruction will be exactly the same problem, CallInUIThreadAndWaitFinishing will never return if the app is terminating :(

Comment: I mean use your code with CallInUIThread, just move it to BeforeDestruction

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar what the most important, this bug show the mess that is done in the background by the arc...

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar: but just do like in sample 2 work, no need to go in beforedestruction. but solution not explain clearly the raison of the bug

Comment: Why? Probably combination of things... Does it really matter why? If you suspect bug in compiler then you should file QP report. But since Tokyo has different threading model it is possible that it will not be opened even though culprit might be somewhere else... another thing would be trying to create threading example that triggers similar error under Tokyo with two anonymous methods and runnable.

Comment: What happens if you don't use in-place anonymous methods but assign them to local variables first?

Comment: The `CallInUIThread` is deprecated in recent versions of Delphi, so I would beware of using it. And as others said, do not call `TThread.Synchronize` from within the main thread. The error itself seems to be caused by the code that is enqueued for execution whilst the class instance is destroyed before its execution. Doing incorrect thing that you're warned not to do is just facing yourself to a risk (in my view `TThread.Synchronize` should never become a static method, or should be safely callable from the main thread).

Comment: @Victoria This question is not about Tokyo, it is about Berlin with quite different threading model. In theory posted code should work even though it might not be called the best practice.

Comment: @Dalija, should. But it doesn't. Ad `CallInUIThread`, it's an advice for future Delphi upgrade. My guess is that the code is queued and executed after the object is destroyed (there were many issues filed for Android platform and this error). In any case, _"you've been warned"_! :)

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar  if i don't use in-place anonymous methods but assign them to local variables then it's work

Comment: @victoria 1) delphi tokyo don't work under android (except if you accept to made application slow like 10 years ago) 2) it's not about callinUIThread nore synchronize but mostly regarding ARC and anonymous method 3) people who say don't use TThread.synchronize in mainthread just don't understand how work TThread.synchronize and 4) before i see how they will correct tokyo CallInUIThread is not deprecated (their is 50% of chance they will need to regress to the previous threading model)

Comment: @loki, aha, so in Embarcadero they don't know how `TThread.Synchronize` works hence they added that note to the docs (I've never had problem with thread sync methods, but I'm not doing what's not supposed to do). If you feel the problem is with anonymous methods, not in thread synchronization calls that you're doing from the main thread, do a simple test - create a method with anonymous method as parameter and call it (without any thread sync function calls).

Comment: @Victoria: `so in Embarcadero they don't know how TThread.Synchronize works hence they added that note to the docs` => **yes exactly**, why it's surprise you ? just read the implementation of TThread.syncrhonize and you will see by yourself ... I don't know where exactly is the problem, this why i start this question ;) but i beat it's about ARC doing mess in background

Comment: @loki, sorry, I cannot (I'm on tablet, so no Delphi). As far as I remember, there is a kind of _current thread is main_ branch, and then.. don't expect me to remember the whole code from there :) I'd still stress enough here to not call thread sync methods from the main thread (it has no meaning). Threading code is modified from version to version, so it may have its meaning. Anyway, have you tried to do what you want from a `TThread` class descendant? Or trying that anonymous method test I suggested (if you suspect that part)?

Comment: @loki It seems that something is broken with anonymous method capture. And error shows because of previous Android threading model. While threading model is changed and exact code now works under Tokyo, it is very likely that method capturing is still broken. Can you please file QP report for this?

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar : it is my 113 reported bug ;) https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-18275 but i don't hope they will one day just look at it :( for them (emb) ARC is the perfect model

Comment: @Victoria : Calling thread.synchronize from the mainthread as meaning when you build generic multi-thread components and you don't know if your method will be call from the main thread or a background thread. in this way you must do if currentthread <> mainthread then executenow else enqueue and it's EXACTLY what do for you thread.synchronize implementation :)

Comment: @Victoria `CallInUIThread` is deprecated, but it is not broken.

Comment: @loki Can you please add code using local variables that works - to show this is method capture issue. Comments on Stack Overflow can vanish at any moment. BTW, you could also post that code with local variables as answer here. While it does not explains why (besides there is some bug) it gives workaround for the issue.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar ok i will do, but as i say i don't think anyone except me and you will never read it :(

Comment: You never know :)

Comment: me what i think:  TThread.synchronize create some hidden local var (because it's access the self object), then CallInUIThread capture also theses local hidden var (i don't know why, let say ARC background mess), and when CallInUIThread finish (after the object is destroyed) then it's try to free theses captures! it's just a supposition ...

Comment: loki, I know this is just an example, but are you sure you need to call a method in the main thread when the class instance is created in a _worker_ thread? If such object is created inside a thread, you know that and you can "synchronize" from that thread class. I mean, does it really need to be a thread safe class that needs to call methods (interlocked operations are not enough)? And if so, an overloaded constructor with a `TThread` parameter in a meaning of "owner" can be useful here. I mean, I would avoid that `TThread.Synchronize` static method without _known_ `AThread` parameter.

Comment: @Dalija, sure, but after Delphi upgrade you'll be resolving it (assuming this is a newly crafted app.)?

Comment: @Victoria : yes, in my case it's because i need to register to listen message (ie openglcontextlost) and crazy but the emb delphi messaging system work only from the mainthread :(

Comment: @Victoria By now it should be obvious that you are barking on the wrong tree. `TThread.Synchronize` is not the core of the problem, it merely surfaces the method capture issue. Also, main point of MCVE is having minimal code that exhibits some problem so the core issue can be easily pinpointed, that code itself does not have to be logical or even useful.

Comment: @Dalija, don't take it bad :) And you might be correct here (sorry, have no Delphi by hand). Then the OP should be able to reproduce the issue in a way I suggested (remove the thread sync code and try it with a similar static method of another class crafted by themselves). Still I'd stay by my point about avoiding `TThread.Synchronize` static method in a way as is shown here.

Comment: @Victoria I have discussed this elsewhere with Loki. The actual methods being called inside the anonymous method in Synchronize are Unsubscribe methods for context-based messages (eg TContextLostMessage) on TMessageManager, which apparently have to be called in the main thread. It should have been a more complete example, and not something so contrived, because it would have explained things better. That the example code works in Tokyo means that either it is *not* to do with ARC, or they fixed ARC in Tokyo. That the threading model changed makes the former way more likely.

Comment: I should add that modifying the example provided so that an instance of TmyObject is created in a *separate thread* (thus ensuring a TRunnable is created) works in Tokyo - i.e. the problem in Berlin is very likely *not* ARC.

Comment: @Dave, thanks for the info. Maybe loki should start a new set of tests narrowing the problem down as I don't seem to follow the point here (maybe someone else does). If I were designing such a class I would subscribe for messaging in constructor, notify an _internally created_ thread by setting some flag that the message arrived by waiting inside for an event (if possible, and messaging is not allowed between threads) and unsubscribe when the class is destroyed. (Un)Subscription and message handling would then happen within the main thread.

Comment: @Dave, sort of `WaitForSingle(Multiple)Object(s)` in WinAPI, just _abstracted_ for all platforms. When the class instance running in the main thread receives the wanted message, it sets that event and the waiting _internal thread_ runs what's needed. Though I don't know if there's such thing implemented for cross platform development (have no Delphi by hand, sorry).

Comment: @Victoria Re your first comment: those were my thoughts, too.

Comment: @Dave, it still applies at this time :) There is no multithreading code shown in the question. If I were designing a class that needs to wait in a worker thread for work, I would wait for an event, posted message (which OP says is impossible at cross platform development) or termination. That's all I can advice here though. I've been working on development of a component that needed to receive tiles from a sophisticated tile server where we simply used events for that. The "internal" thread that was responsible to get tiles has been waiting to the event (only Windows we support though).

Comment: @DaveNottage I would not exclude that issue is ARC related because different threading model means different timing and behavior in ARC code. But, since you couldn't reproduce issue using runnable opens up possibility that ARC is not the culprit. It might as well be just bad codegen or whatever...